# Python string search - starting from a specific position within a string

Tags: python-3.x, search

I have the following text stored in a variable which has additional text before and after it:

`'content="80.96"abcd'`

I have a search variable from which I find out the location of: content="

But then I need another search to find the location of the second quotation mark, using the end position which I found out from the previous search as the starting point for this second search. Is it possible to do that kind of search, from a certain starting position in a string, using re.search?

You see, my goal is to get the 80.96, the price of some stock. However, for another stock, it could be fewer or greater number of digits. My ultimate goal is to search for the position of the second " so that I can calculate the length of the stock price and extract it.

Using Python 3.4.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your way/question

> My ultimate goal is to search for the position of the second " so that
>   I can calculate the length of the stock price and extract it.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'content="80.96"abcd'
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer('"', text)] # gets double quotes indices
[8, 14]
>>> text[8:14+1]
'"80.96"'
```

### A better way might be just to grab the decimal stock quote

```
>>> m = re.search("\d+.\d+", text)
>>> m.group()
'80.96'
```

Then I recommend you store the quotation as a `Decimal` data type, `float` is approximate, and when it comes to financial trading, you will get "rounding" error with some operations

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(m.group())
Decimal('80.96')
```

Comment: Used logic from your first example and it worked. From the end location found from my first search (content=), I took a string 15 characters long. Then I looped through each letter adding +1 to a counter until I found ". This is the end point I was looking for to get my stock price no matter how long or short it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly. You just want to get the decimal from the string. Assuming that all strings are of the same format i.e. `content="<decimal>"cccc`.

You can split the string and then use a regex to do that:

```
In [1]: a = 'content="80.96"abcd'

In [2]: a.split('=')
Out[2]: ['content', '"80.96"abcd']

In [3]: b = a.split('=')[1]

In [4]: b
Out[4]: '"80.96"abcd'

In [5]: import re

In [6]: p = re.compile(ur'\"(\d*\.?\d*)\"')

In [7]: re.search(p, b)
Out[7]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x3ad2af8>

In [8]: obj = re.search(p, b)

In [9]: obj.group()
Out[9]: '"80.96"'

In [10]: s = obj.group()

In [11]: s
Out[11]: '"80.96"'

In [12]: s[1 : -1]
Out[12]: '80.96'
```

As a program it would be:

```
import re

def getDecimal(string):
    part_2 = string.split('=')[1]
    pattern = re.compile(ur'\"(\d*\.?\d*)\"')
    obj = re.search(pattern, part_2)
    return obj.group()[1 : -1]

print(getDecimal('content="83520.96652"asdf')) # Output: 83520.96652
```

Comment: Thanks used a simpler technique as commented in first response above. Will note yours for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to go through all of the characters.

```
text='content="80.96"abcd'
record='no'
stock=[]
for letter in text:
    if letter=='"' and record=='no':
        record='yes':
    elif letter=='"' and record=='yes':
        record='no':
    elif record=='yes':
        stock.append(letter)
stock=''.join(stock)
print(stock)
```

This way, the program will print the stock.